# Debian Bash Shell Variable Substitution error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I want to use a bash script to call other scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
./anotherScript $1 $2
./anotherScript $3 $4
#and so on
```

I don't know how many variables will be passed, so I am using a variable 'i' to run from 0 to $# and trying to get ${$i} as the argument.
However Bash gives me a bad substitution error. I have tried the following:

```
a=1
echo $a
echo ${$a} #doesn't work
echo ${${a}} #doesn't work
```

None of them work. I am expecting ${$a} to evaluate to ${1} which should give me the first argument. I have looked through the man page and also the bash scripting guide [on the Linux Documentation Project site](http://www.tldp.org/guides.html)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash, you can do an indirect reference with a `!`:

```
echo ${!a}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    ./anotherscript $1 $2
    shift 2
done
```

You can tune that to decide what happens with an odd number of arguments.

Comment: That will also work, since my script will never have an off number of arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I gave William Pursell an upvote.  Another way to do this is to assign values to an array (which would be 0 relative):

```
list=("$@")
a=0
echo ${list[a]}
a=1
echo ${list[a]}
```